# Autoloader in Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks

If a file is read by autoloader and write has failed what happens when next time we run the stream? Will it omit those files or will it take again in the streaming process?

I was trying to read and write the data using autoloader. Read is working fine and write too..But sometimes the write is getting failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Autoloader stores information about what files were successfully processed, and will process again in case of failure.

Databricks Documentation:

> In case of failures, Auto Loader can resume from where it left off by information stored in the checkpoint location and continue to provide exactly-once guarantees when writing data into Delta Lake.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/